# StringWithFormat min width

Tags: iphone

I know that this is possible, but can't seem to find it.  I need to format a string (using stringWithFormat) with 3 0's when the value is <100.

So my integer i = 5, the string should be @"005", but I can't remember or find the format specifier to make this happen.

Hopefully this is low hanging fruit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was ask:

%03d works great.